# template programming: ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-c++

I am implementing a sorting algorithm as personal training (no homework!).
I have the following code (excluding imports etc.):

```
        template<class RandomIt, class Compare>
        void sort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp)
        {
            /* actual sorting code is here */
        }

        template<class RandomIt>
        void sort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last)
        {
            std::function<bool(decltype(*first), decltype(*last))> comp = [](decltype(*first) a, decltype(*last) b)
            {
                return a < b;
            };

            sort (first, last, comp);
        }
```

Trying to call this code with a test array

```
    auto test_array_1 = std::make_unique <std::array < uint64_t,SORTING_TEST_LENGTH >> ();
    std::copy(std::cbegin(*template_array), std::cend(*template_array), std::begin(*test_array_1));

    sort(std::begin(*test_array_1), std::end(*test_array_1));
```

The compiler complains about "ambiguous call to overloaded function" (VC++ C2668). From my understanding the call should not be ambiguous though. Also giving the call in the second sort function the template parameters for the first sort function does not have any effect.

What am I missing here? Why does the compiler consider the second call "ambiguous"?

Comment: Try giving the whole error... any help on our part would be just shooting in the dark.

Comment: This might happen if you have a ``using namespace foo`` (``std`` being the obvious culprit for ``foo``) which already has a ``sort``.

Comment: Interestingly enough I do not have a ```using namespace std``` anywhere in my code (I hate namespace pollution).

Comment: Welcome to ADL, where `std::sort` can be found because the iterators produced by `std::begin` are in the `std` namespace, pulling in `std::sort`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That is somewhat unexpected. What do you mean by ADL?

Comment: Argument Dependent Lookup - basically, for unqualified function calls, look in the namespaces of the arguments, their template parameters, their base classes, and also the namespaces of their dogs great-great-grandmother.

Comment: Puppy, I think that is a good answer to the question. Would you write that as an answer for future readers?

Comment: @rich and you think that because?

Comment: `std::function<bool(decltype(*first), decltype(*last))> comp = [](decltype(*first) a, decltype(*last) b)` -- replace that type with `auto`.  Stop prematurely pessimizing your code.  Type erase only when you need to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is two fold.

First, `sort` is found via ADL, so you get two overloads, and they both match.  In general, naming functions the same as `std` functions when you are not trying to ADL-overload is fraught, due to the possibility of ADL-induced ambiguity.

Now, this only happens when passing types from `namespace std;`  Sometimes iterators are from this namespace, but not in this case : `array` uses raw pointer iterators.  The trigger for ADL finding `std::sort` is the `std::function`.

Which brings me to the next problem: there is very little to be gained, and much to be lost, by `std::function` in the above code.  Replace it with `auto`.  Pass low level sorting algorithms an inlineable comparison object.

You still do not want to call it `sort`.  If you call it `sort` you need to qualify calls with the namespace, or `(sort)` to block ADL.

The ADL rule is that both the "usual" functions, and functions in the namespace of arguments, and namespace of what arguments point to, and template arguments of arguments, etc, are considered for overload resolution.  This is Argument Dependent Lookup, or ADL, or Koenig lookup.  It means that namespace pollution of a kind can occur when using types from another namespace (which is sad), but it also makes some nice magic happen (like std::cout << "hello world\n";`)

Comment: Good explanation. Just want to point out the choice of the name ```sort``` was deliberate, as I want to stick to the standard library interface. I know the standard library implementation will be better, but as mentioned the whole project is a training exercise for me to become better in certain aspects of C++.